# Program crashes - Division by zero

Tags: c++, pointers, scanf

My code goes like this:

```
if (x[b] != x[c] && x[a] != x[b])
{
    if(x[a] != x[b] != x[c] != x[d])
    {
        if(y[a] != y[b] != y[c] != y[d])
        {
            int m = (y[a] - y[b])/(x[a] - x[b]);
            int b = y[a] - x[a] * m;
            if((y[c] - x[c]*m > b && y[d] - x[d]*m > b)|| (y[c] - x[c]*m < b && y[d] - x[d]*m < b)){
                m = (y[b] - y[c])/(x[b] - x[c]);
                b = y[b] - x[b] * m;
                if((y[a] - x[a]*m > b && y[d] - x[d]*m > b)|| (y[a] - x[a]*m < b && y[d] - x[d]*m < b))
                {
                    int xx[4];
                    int yy[4];
                    xx[0] = x[a];
                    xx[1] = x[b];
                    xx[2] = x[c];
                    xx[3] = x[d];
                    yy[0] = y[a];
                    yy[1] = y[b];
                    yy[2] = y[c];
                    yy[3] = y[d];
                    if(c == 1)
                    {
                        c = 0;
                        pt = povrsina(xx, yy);
                            pc = p - pt;
                    }
                    pv = povrsina(xx, yy);
                    pr = p - pv;
                    if(pr < pc)
                    {
                        pc = pr;
                        pt = pv;
                    }
                    else if(pr == pc)
                    {
                        pt = max(pt, pv);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The input I have tried is this:

```
5
30
0  0
10 0
0  10
10 10
7  3
```

My program crashes with an error code for `Division by zero` in line 174:

```
m = (y[b] - y[c])/(x[b] - x[c]);
```

So I added the first `if` statement checking

```
if x[b] != x[c]
```

but it still crashes for some reason with the same error code and in the same line.

Comment: You make two arrays of pointers, but you never make the pointers point anywhere. That leads to *undefined behavior* when you dereference them.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `int x[n]` and `int y[n]`; then `scanf("%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]);`, though how do I know what you're going to achieve here (since you didn't tell).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have tried doing it without pointers, still chrashes. As to why I tagged it as c++ is because I'm writing in c++ and compiling with the c++ compiler, I'm just using scanf and printf because they're usually faster than cin and cout.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I did try without pointers, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Shouldn't matter, the `"%d"` format should skip leading white-space.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah true

Comment: I'm gonna add the whole code now to see if someone can help me.

Comment: I would also love to know why 2 people down voted and why?

Comment: If somebody would remove the on hold tag that would be great, I edited the question which now states the actual error.

Comment: Umm, `x[b] = x[c]` *sets* x[b] to equal x[c], guaranteeing a division by zero.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't have that line anywhere in my code the if statement goes like this if you didn't read:
    if (x[b] != x[c] && x[a] != x[b])
That's the very first if statement

Comment: @Saizaku That's not what your question says. Look right after "So I added the first if statement"...

Comment: That was a typing mistake thanks for pointing it out I was referring  to the complete code which has the correct if statement, I'll edit that now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following works correctly.

```
int n = 0;
double p  = 0;

scanf("%d\n%lf", &n, &p);

int *x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
int *y = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]);
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%d %d\n", x[i], y[i]);
}
```

See the [**demo**](https://ideone.com/hx4Oik).

> Update

Your code is crashing because of the following line.

```
int m = (y[a] - y[b])/(x[a] - x[b]);
```

Think if the value of `a, b, c, d` is `0, 2, 3, 4`, then the denominator term `(x[a] - x[b])` represents `(x[0] - x[2])` which is equal to zero, right? Because the 1st and 3rd input is `0 0` and `0 10`.

If you divide a value by zero, then it becomes infinity and your program will crash at that time. **While writing statement with division operation, make sure the divisor is not zero.**

Comment: I have updated my code. I request to reconsider downvoting!

Comment: I am not the one who down voted, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have added the complete code, if you can take a look that would be great.

Comment: @Saizaku don't edit repeatedly! ask a different question. you can accept my answer which I believe, helped you to identify the problem.